# Show content from other website

Tags: html, load, show

Okay is it possible that when user opens ex. www.google.com he load content from another website but keeps the url same? All I want is when I open on my computer ex. www.google.com he loads me some other site. Or is it posibble that when I open site ex. www.google.com he instead of it loads the HTML code I wrote?

Comment: hmmm.. why would you want that ?

Comment: Why would you want this? Do you want to spoof the page?

Comment: When my friend comes over and when he checks this site I want it to be diffrent. I will copy the source of the site adn change just this tiny little thing.

Comment: Ah that explains your other comment about using Greasemonkey. Next time if you ask a question, please what you want to accomplish, instead of how you think you should accomplish that and asking about that instead. You may want to update your question to reflect what you really want. I've just answered this revised question up front.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you're really asking, but if you control the source code of the site (so NOT www.google.com) you can embed content from another site via an `iframe`

```
<iframe src="http://www.othersite.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: I need a Greasemonkey script that will load some site instead of another. Do you understand now what I want? I trought like using something like this

<frameset>
<frame src="http://actual-url.example.com/page.html">
</frameset>

But It won`t work.

Comment: You cannot use javascript to point the browser to a different site without changing the url. For security reasons, javascript does not allow that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make the browser use an http [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) (transparent or not) that you control, you can serve whatever content you want.
Remember to not be evil though.

Comment: What about url masking, or just loading other page with Greasemonkey?

Comment: What I mean here is that when the http request for www.example.com reaches the proxy, you return the content (html) you want over the socket to the browser. The browser url will still say www.example.com.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking into using Greasemonkey to change some element on the page (as per your own comment on your question and @idrumgood's answer), I suggest taking a look at this:

http://www.tuxradar.com/content/greasemonkey-beginners

It looks like this is exactly what you are looking for ([Google is your friend](https://www.google.nl/search?q=greasemonkey+change+page), first result here...)